# How can make this code DRY?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to avoid repetition in the following code:

```
is_on = True

def func1():
    global is_on
    if is_on:
        pass

def func2():
    global is_on
    if is_on:
        pass

def func3():
    global is_on
    if is_on:
        pass
```

I am using Python 3.6.5

Edit: each func has a code to be executed when they are called (instead of `pass`), but only if the variable `is_on` evaluate to `True`, this variable can be changed by another code so that when these func are called they wont do anything. Sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: By `pass`, do you mean that you want the functions to return `None`? And what if not `is_on`? what kind of purposes all these functions supposed to serve?

Comment: Well, since none of your three functions do anything, you can just delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im guessing you want all the functions to start by doing the same things and then do something else, if this is the case you should use a decorator.

Try using a decorator

```
@some_decorator
def some_func():
    # Do something


def some_decorator(func):
    def new_function(*args):
        if (not is_on):
            return
        func_result = func(*args)
        return func_result
    return new_function
```

Basically what happens here is every time some_func is called it receives a new function object from the decorator which tests your request and calls the function if the 'if' statement is true.

Also as stated in the comments no reason to use global, since there is no other variable with the same name.

Comment: Since you dont assign to `is_on` in the any function body, you can remove `global is_on`. Also, a little too much guessing for my taste. Hopefully OP will clarify the requirements.

Comment: @timgeb You are correct about the global argument thing, but I have no idea what he wants to do so I just copy pasted from his code :) I guessed this is what he wanted cause otherwise his question makes zero sense.. Ill wait for clarification anyways..

Comment: @timgeb He clarified, seems like this exactly what he wanted :)

Comment: Good. Voted to reopen and +1.

Comment: I would say however that using a decorator in order to not repeat a single if check in some functions seems overkill to me. Applying the decorator is a line you would have to repeat, too...